# Regarding .Net Maui Blazor

Tags: maui

In .Net Maui Blazor how can I set colour for various themes (like Dark Mode and Light Theme)

I am unable to find the solution of the above Problem?Hoe can i Provide styling that it will be auto adjusted for both Dark theme and Light Theme.

Comment: Could you please share some relevant code about how you design your UI, which helps us understand what your expected result? By the way, do you mean [Theme an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/theming?view=net-maui-8.0) and [Respond to system theme changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes?view=net-maui-8.0)?

Comment: Hello, I suggest you to read in order to create valuable questions to the community - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example